# Commas in "to my surprise"?

Tags: commas

Is:

> I peeked around the corner and, to my surprise, my classmate was crying in the corner.

proper comma placement?

I have a feeling it's not

Comment: I peeked around the corner and, to my surprise, my classmate was in the crying in the corner.

Comment: I'd usually want a sizeable pause after the 'and'. "I peeked around the corner. And, to my surprise, there my classmate was – crying." (You've too many corners to make for clear reading.)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I would use commas there.

However I think it is a matter of judgement and style, e.g.

*If we had really never met again, I could have borne it, but to my surprise we chanced to meet in the capital.*   [no commas]
[The Sea of Regret: Two Turn-of-the Century Chinese Romantic Novels](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Arv6Ii_c4bYC&pg=PA98&dq=%22to%20my%20surprise%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAWoVChMIzcL45PDMyAIVx9saCh0QOAYB#v=onepage&q=%22to%20my%20surprise%22&f=false)

*A few weeks later, much to my surprise, I was in beautiful Vancouver.*  [commas]
[The Surprise of My Life: An Autobiography By Claire Drainie Taylor](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=IKgztFeklb4C&pg=PA266&dq=%22to%20my%20surprise%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMIzcL45PDMyAIVx9saCh0QOAYB#v=onepage&q=%22to%20my%20surprise%22&f=false)

To see other examples have a look at this search from [Google Books](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22to%20my%20surprise%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1967,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=6AMkVt7iBIaAU_KpjpAC#lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1%2Ccd_min:1967%2Ccd_max:2000%2Clr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&q=%22to%20my%20surprise%22).

Comment: Your edit needs adjusting. // You're attempting to leave a comprehensible question, but I'm not sure if it is exactly what OP was asking about. The dash has an influence on other punctuation.

Comment: I've corrected it. It was a cut-and-paste from the OP's example in a comment. However, I don't see a dash (?)

Comment: Ah: it's the site's attempt at a score-through of an ellipsis. // 'I peeked around the corner, and to my surprise there he was.' is getting a little in need of comma support for clarity. The Locative-S-V structure (which OP gave) makes this a special case IMO. /  'I peeked around the corner and, to my surprise, there he was.' I'm not really happy with this, either. Substituting dashes works better for me here. Otherwise, the 'and' seems too cosily ensconced with 'around the corner'; a dash exerts more long-range disruption. Or I'd signal the pause after 'corner', as in the comment above.

Comment: I'm not sure why the phantom downvote; I think your two examples are relevant to the general situation.

Comment: Oh, it'll be a revenge vote from someone I criticised elsewhere. - No worries!